# CSV quick plot error

Tags: csv, shiny

I would like to use the CSV quick plot application to analyze data however even with all the packages installed the app continues to show an error. The error message is: 
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  cannot open file
The code is below:
UI

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Quick Plot"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('infile', 'Choose file to upload',
              accept = c(
                'text/csv',
                'text/comma-separated-values',
                'text/tab-separated-values',
                'text/plain',
                '.csv',
                '.tsv'
              )
    ),
    selectInput("plotType", label = "Select Plot Type",
                c("Histogram" = "hist",
                  "Correlation" = "corr")),
    dateInput("date", "Date:"),  
    submitButton("Submit")


  ),
  mainPanel(
    h3('Output Information'),
    h4('File entered'),
    verbatimTextOutput("ofile"),
    h4('You selected plot type'),
    verbatimTextOutput("oplotType"),
    h4('You entered'),
    verbatimTextOutput("odate"),
    plotOutput('newHist')
  )
))
```

server

```
library(UsingR)
library(shiny)
library(Hmisc)
library(corrplot)
wd <- getwd()
setwd(wd)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    output$ofile        <- renderPrint({input$infile})
    output$oplotType    <- renderPrint({input$plotType})
    output$odate        <- renderPrint({input$date})

    plotdata <- reactive({
      filestr <- input$infile
      read.csv(filestr$name)
      if(is.null(input$file1)) 
        return(NULL)
    })

    output$newHist <- renderPlot({
      hist(plotdata())
    })

    #   Conditional plot selection is test in progress
    #     corrdf <- cor(plotdata)
    #     output$newHist <- renderPlot({
    #         corrplot(corrdf, method = "circle")
    #     })

  }
)
```

Please help me in getting this application to run. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please mention the exact error you are getting ? Because I am getting the following error :
`Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection`

Comment: i experience the same error you are getting. After uploading a file i receive the following error Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  cannot open file ' ': No such file or directory

Comment: Initial error is because, before uploading the file, your app is trying to display the plot and as there is no data(as there is no file) to display, it throws an error.  There is a get around for not displaying the initial error. Include the following into the `mainPanel` in `ui.R`: 
`tags$style(type="text/css",
               ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"),`
Can you please  edit your question with the file/ equivalent sample file you are trying to upload ?

Comment: the iris data set is equivalent.https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=iris+dataset+download&oq=iris+dataset+&gs_l=serp.1.1.0i67l6j0l4.1483.1483.0.3348.1.1.0.0.0.0.129.129.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.129.2cgEroGajEQ

Comment: I hope @daattali's answer resolves your situation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems with your code.

1. you're checking for `if(is.null(input$file1))` but I believe you want to use `input$infile`
2. the above check should be done BEFORE `read.csv` because if there is no file chosen, you don't want to read a file
3. when reading the file you want to use `filestr$datapath` instead of `filestr$name`. The name only gives you the name of the file on the user's local machine, while the datapath gives the actual full path to the file that's been uplodaed

Here is a simplification of your app that only deals with selecting a file and reading it into csv, demonstrating all those points

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput('infile', 'Choose file to upload',
              accept = c(
                'text/csv',
                'text/comma-separated-values',
                'text/tab-separated-values',
                'text/plain',
                '.csv',
                '.tsv'
              )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    plotdata <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$infile)) {
        return()
      }
      filestr <- input$infile
      read.csv(filestr$datapath)
    })

    observe({
      cat(str(plotdata()))
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks @daattali how could I add the scatter-plot and histogram from the imported csv file?

Comment: Well in my dummy app, `plotdata()` holds a dataframe with the contents of the csv file. Use that to plot or do whatever you need, I just solved the issue of why you weren't able to get the data.